# msvcrt.dll issue when installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable on windows server 2003

Tags: visual-c++, dll

When I attempt to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable I get the following error.

[image]

I have an updated msvcrt.dll to replace the current one with but every time I delete/replace the old dll windows re adds the old one into the system32 folder again.

Comment: MSVC2010 redist is unrelated to msvcrt.dll. The latter is a system component and you should not modify it.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I was under the impression that Updating to 2010 redistributable would update msvcrt.dll but that was not the case.  But for some reason on one of our 2003 server machines when I tried to install it it would bring up this error.  However on other all the other ones I tried it installed successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be useful to know the OS version you are using. Could be Windows 2000 or XP (my guess from the screenshot, but could be over RDP as well).

When `msvcrt.dll` became a first-class citizen (i.e. a system DLL) some time during the lifetime of XP, some changes were also made to it. Incompatible changes, I should add. Example: if you built a program against the VS CRT in former times (e.g. using the WDK/DDK) you could rely on the fact that it works starting with the least common denominator of existing `msvcrt.dll` versions. However, at some point MS decided that programs built to target, say, XP could rely on the new functionality that was snuck into newer versions of `msvcrt.dll`. Hence the observed incompatibility.

One way to make it work could be to add a file `msvcrt.dll.local` in the same folder or - failing that - to create a shim that enforced your intended behavior. See [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2011/06/17/demystifying-shims-or-using-the-app-compat-toolkit-to-make-your-old-stuff-work-with-your-new-stuff.aspx).

Comment: Windows server 2003 and yes I am remoting into the server.

Answer (score 1):

Got similar error. Fixed it by restarting the server before the install.